# Lines of colored pixel

Tags: java, swing, graphics

In a component I must display several lines of colored pixels.  Each pixel of the line is given a color.  What kind of component is suitable to build the line or what kind of component is suitable to hold pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the best (but maybe not easiest) way would be implementing a custom `Paint` class that allows for setting colour regions - a bit like the `GradientPaint` classes but more flexible.

Then you would call `Graphics2D.setPaint(myPaint)` just before you draw the line.

The `Paint` implementation could offer a method `setColorForRegion(double start, double end, Color color)` with `start` and `end` taking values between 0.0 and 1.0 to mark a region on the line.

Might be a bit complicated to implement the `Paint` class, but the benefit is, that you can resize the lines and draw them in any direction while preserving the color pattern.

Comment: That's a bit like the first solution i tried.  I'm using a LinearGradientPaint to paint a polygon.  I was worried about the performance, cause i'm creating a new LinearGradientPaint every seconds to fill a polygon every seconds.

Comment: Using JLabel doesn't seem to be a viable solution, because each pixel in the line should be placed in component from its coordinate and a has a value that define its color.  So i have an object that represent the pixel with the coordinate and the color value.  Now i must find a way to build the line placing each pixel object at the right place with the right color.

Comment: @wotan2009 if you measure (and only then!) performance problems, you can cache the gradient and only rebuild if anything that effects its appearance has changed

Answer (score 3):

Just extend `JComponent` and paint the lines/pixels in the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: ... this just moves the *coloured line drawing problem* into another container. Looks like wotan already has a component.

Comment: and little bit different is painting for nonResiziable and for Resiziable Component, look like Andreas_D's sugestion about GradientPaint (in JLabel) should be easiest and safiest way